# Как получить доступ к отображаемому элементу ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Как мне из кода обратиться к массиву TextBlock в коде

```
<Window.Resources>
    <x:Array x:Key="someArray" Type="{x:Type local:ItemForListBox}">
        <local:ItemForListBox X="100"/>
        <local:ItemForListBox X="200"/>
        <local:ItemForListBox X="300"/>
        <local:ItemForListBox X="400"/>
    </x:Array>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Click="Button_Click_1">1234</Button>

    <ItemsControl Name="list" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{StaticResource ResourceKey=someArray}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=X}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Попробуйте через коллекцию Items в объекте list.

Comment: @Alex не все так просто. Таким образом я получаю источник данных.

Comment: А зачем вам? Вам не должно этого хотеться.

Comment: @VladD Да уже незачем, была мысль на счет извращенного рисования круга с сегментами через Code behind :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем так делать нельзя,если вы столкнулись с таким-же вопросом, то вы что-то делаете не так как надо :-)

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно Вас понял:

```
string[] items = list.Items
            .OfType<ItemForListBox>()
            .Select(item => item.X)
            .ToArray();
```